# Did I interpret this question correctly? ( Sequences and Series Problem)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that a sack containing 50 kg of rice has a small hole that steadily gets larger.  For the first minute, 1/3 kg of rice leaks out.  For each succeeding minute, 1/3 kg more rice leak out as compared to the previous minute.  How many kg of rice would be left in the sack after 15 minutes?

Solution:
$a_{1}=\frac{1}{3}$

$a_{15}=\frac{1}{3} +(15-1)(\frac{1}{3} )=5\  kg$

After $15$ minutes, the amount of rice in the sack is $50 -5 = 45$ kg.

Did I interpret the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't interpret it correctly.

The amount of rice being lost per minute increases as an arithmetic progression. First term = common difference = $\frac 13$.

What you've calculated is the "last term", which is the rice lost only in the $15$th minute alone.

What you need to calculate is the total rice lost from first to fifteenth minute, which is the sum of the arithmetic series.

After that, you subtract this from the initial quantity to get the rice remaining.

Can you proceed?

> $S_{15} = \frac{15}2(2(\frac 13)+ (15-1)(\frac 13)) = 40$. Hence remaining rice = $50-40 =10$ kg.

Comment: Since s_{15}=\  40, to get the total amount left in the sack, we have 50-40= 10 kgs.

Comment: @MarkLarson That's right.

Comment: Since $s_{15}=\ 40$, to get the total amount left in the sack, we have 50-40= 10 kgs.